# Strangeness in Conversion from String to Double in C++

Tags: c++, string, double, data-conversion

I have to read some data (with `double` precision) from a text file. Sometimes, I get strange results when converting from `string` to `double` with `atof`. The following is a code snippet which demonstrates the problem -- note that I am using a GNU C++ 4.8.1 compiler. The code simply prints out the numbers which are between -0.1 and 0 taking steps of size 0.01; so only, 9 numbers are expected.

```
    #include <iostream>
    #include <cstdlib>

    int main() {
    int y;
    double a, b = 0.0, x = 1e-2, z;

    double a_string = atof("-0.1");
    double a_inline = -0.1;

    std::cout << "Inline:: ";
    a = a_inline;
    for (y = 1 ; (z = a + y * x) < b; ++y){
    std::cout << y << ": " << z << " | ";
    }

    std::cout << "\nString:: ";
    a = a_string;
    for (y = 1 ; (z = a + y * x) < b; ++y){
    std::cout << y << ": " << z << " | ";
    }

    return 0;
    }
```

The result is

```
    Inline:: 1: -0.09 | 2: -0.08 | 3: -0.07 | 4: -0.06 | 5: -0.05 | 6: -0.04 | 7: -0.03 | 8: -0.02 | 9: -0.01 | 
    String:: 1: -0.09 | 2: -0.08 | 3: -0.07 | 4: -0.06 | 5: -0.05 | 6: -0.04 | 7: -0.03 | 8: -0.02 | 9: -0.01 | 10: -3.46945e-18 |
```

Note that the `for` loop based on the string assignment (`a_string`) runs one time more than the loop based on the inline assignment (`a_inline`) -- notice the last number `-3.46945e-18`. Having read other relevant posts on string-to-double conversion, still I could not figure out why this happens.

Comment: Note: It behaves as expected (9 values per loop) on my rig. (Apple LLVM version 5.1 (clang-503.0.40) (based on LLVM 3.4svn)), compiled as x64. Interestingly, different results come from [**Coliru**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c918637b84884a8d) vs. [**ideone.com**](https://ideone.com/LO4yrb).

Comment: It works good also for me, GNU C++ 4.3.2, x64

Comment: It seems to me that atof("-0.1") must working as string parser, so it can't work as just getting -0.1 value from "-0.1" string, it gets final value by summing some values row and multiplying it on -1.0 (in your case -1.0 * 0.1). I think this multiplication is the reason. After it your string value will be something like -0.100000000000001.

Comment: it woeks good also for me, VS2012, x64

Comment: @Fomin Arseniy there is no apparent accumulation in the loop.

Comment: Even though this link talks about using floating point variables as loop counters, the same applies to using floating point computation in any section of the for() loop:  https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/FLP30-CPP.+Do+not+use+floating+point+variables+as+loop+counters

Comment: I was not saying about accumulation error but about error in start value of a_string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code amounts to...

```
std::atof("-0.1") - 10 * 1e-2
```

...not equaling exactly 0.  That's life with real number representations, which are only approximations capable of encoding a finite number of points spread across their range, and some of the functions generating/handling them may introduce errors in the last digit or two even for numbers than happen to be perfectly representable.  In your case, -0.1 can not be perfectly represented.  To get a feel for this, type "-0.1" into the "Decimal Representation" text box in [this online IEEE 754 Converter](http://www.h-schmidt.net/FloatConverter/IEEE754.html), and you'll see that the binary representation possible in 32-bit `float`s is only approximate... in this case that's equally true of what's possible in 64-bit `double`s... you just have a better approximation.

The usual advice is to go read [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating Point Values](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

What's mathematically "x - x" may not be 0 when the calculation of each x has been done differently or at different times, and exactly how it pans out can vary with optimisation level, surrounding code, hardware, compiler etc..  It's a bit of an art form designing code that handles these issues gracefully.  In your case, if you want 9 iterations of the loop then count to 9, if you want some tolerance in the comparison then write something that allows a small margin for error (an "epsilon" value) in the comparison.  You can also use functions that bump floating point numbers to the next representable value one bit at a time, which avoids issues with scaling an epsilon value so it corresponds to the last significant digit or two with the specific exponents involved, but that's a bit of a game too as it's hard to know how many representation and rounding errors accumulated in the generation of a value.

Answer (score 4):

Binary floats are usually not exact representations of decimal fractions. Direct comparisons of different computed results or of computed results with literals are bound to fail unintuitively. You must work with intervals when comparing. The problem has little to do with atof as such.